# Create EF Core as separate project in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm trying to create a separate EF Core 2 as separate project.

I created a class library (.net core), add two references: `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`, `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design`

Then I met an error like:

> The specified framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '2.0' was not found

I solved by adding in root folder a json file called `global.json` which content is:

```
{
   "sdk": {
      "version": "2.0.2"
   }
}
```

Good until here.

If I run command: `dotnet ef update database` it tells that:

> No database provider has been configured for this DbContext.

Most of people said that I have to register in `Startup.cs`. But I don't have it because the project is class library, no mvc core application.

So, what steps to do in this case ?

Of course, I have a separate project for mvc core which has reference to that EF core project. Should I register the dbcontext in that `Startup.cs` file ?

Comment: Basically the limitation is, that you need an lunchable application to perform dotnet commands. You usually do that with the `-p/--project` (when run form the startup applications folder) or `-s/--startup-project` when run from the library folder. This is required so that the correct provider and connection string is loaded from Startup.cs/Program.cs

Answer (score 3):

Assuming nothing had changed in the last few weeks since I did this:

Create class `DesignTimeDbContextFactory` (replacing `ApplicationDbContext` with the name of your `DbContext`:

```
public class DesignTimeDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var connectionString = "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=MyDbName;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true";

        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>();

        builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);

        return new ApplicationDbContext(builder.Options);
    }
}
```

Now do one of the following:

- if using the Add-Migration and Update-Database commandlets use the -project [project-name] flag
- if using dotnet from command line use the --project [project-name] flag
- or you can ensure that this class library is set as startup project and also set in the PM console the 'Default Project' and then add your migrations and update the database

Comment: Only one comment on this one. It is pretty much 100% correct apart from the fact that the usage of  `--project <ProjectName>` at the end of the command won't require him to set the startup project as a different one.

Comment: Thanks @Elfocrash. Have updated with a few options on the final part. It seems to work differently through VS to doing it through command line so hopefully this will help all.

Comment: Thanks for comment. So, for identity, how to proceed in this way ?

Comment: In general, this is the correct approach. However, using JSON config buys you nothing here. You're still duplicating the connection string across projects and since this is a class library, environments won't come into play (which you aren't even using environment specific JSON config, anyways). You might as well just hard-code the connection string in the code, as the docs do. As the name implies, `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` should only be used in development anyways.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisPratt for pointing out about the config. I use the config file as I sometimes switch between LocalDb and an Azure DB so that I can manually test migrations. I have updated the answer.

Comment: @SnakeEyes - not sure what you're asking about Identity. It should work in the same was as any other project using EF.